# Detect if entity is attached to a datacontext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've a procedure where I need to save an entity object. The problem is that I don't know if this entity is attached to my datacontext or not. To solve this I use the following code:

```
try
{
    db.ClientUsers.Attach(clientUser);
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, clientUser);
}
catch { }

db.SubmitChanges();
```

I'm looking for a better method to detect if an entity belongs to a context and also to test if an entity is attached to a specific context.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wonder... what does [`GetOriginalEntityState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548700.aspx) return for a non-attached object? Even if it throws an exception, it'll probably be faster than a refresh...

(update) - a test shows it returns null:

```
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        Customer orig = ctx.Customers.GetOriginalEntityState(cust);
        Assert.IsNull(orig);

        cust = new Customer();
        ctx.Customers.Attach(cust);
        orig = ctx.Customers.GetOriginalEntityState(cust);
        Assert.IsNotNull(orig);
        Assert.AreNotSame(cust,orig);
```

So perhaps use `GetOriginalEntityState` and check for null returned value...

Comment: This is great! Makes for a nice "IsAttached(Of T)" extension method for DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

I think a better solution is this:

```
ObjectStateEntry stateEntry = null;
if (context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out stateEntry))
{
    //you know you are attached!
}
```

Found on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/49e97c25-7325-457a-891b-8fd58c726f3e.

Comment: That's not Linq to Sql